# Saber a que red Wifi esta conectado iphone iOS 12 - Xamarin .Net

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Estoy teniendo problemas para recuperar en nombre de la red Wifi al que está conectado el usuario. Antes de la version iOS 12 funcionaba bien, pero parece que cambiaron algunas directivas.

El código que tengo y funcionaba es:

```
private WiFiNetwork ConectedWifi()
{
    WiFiNetwork result = new WiFiNetwork();
    NSDictionary dict;
    var status =  CaptiveNetwork.TryCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("en0", out dict); //Aqui me dict queda como null
    if (status != StatusCode.NoKey)
    {

        var bssid = dict[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeyBSSID];
        var ssid = dict[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeySSID];
        var ssiddata = dict[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeySSIDData];

        result.Name = ssid.ToString();
        result.MacAddress = bssid.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Leyendo dice que hay que agrear el permiso `com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info` `value:YES` en `Entitlements.plist`, lo hice y también log agregué en `AppId`, pero sigue sin funcionar. ¿Alguien que me de una mano?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539526/getting-the-ssid-of-the-connected-wifi-on-ios-12-xamarin) mencionan que tienen el mismo problema, la única diferencia es que hay [comentario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539526/getting-the-ssid-of-the-connected-wifi-on-ios-12-xamarin#comment92407656_52551587) que de igual manera se debe regenerar el *provisioning profile*, lo demás es justamente lo que ya has intentando

Comment: en esta [pregunta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712535/how-do-i-use-captivenetwork-to-get-the-current-wifi-hotspot-name/33132454#33132454) puede que encuentres lo que buscas. en practica tenes que abilitar la funcionalidad de accesso a las informaciones de WI-FI deste **X-Code**  el cual agrega automaticamente la autorización

Comment: En que parte o que pasos hay que seguir para habilitarla desde X-Code? yo lo agregue en el panel de developers de apple y en el .plist

Comment: Tal vez alguno de estos comentarios te ayude. [Adding "Access WiFi Information" entitlement for iOS 12 apps](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/349047/). Aunque imagino que ya has leído casi todo si estás tan urgido. Saludos

Comment: Probaste con las librerias de James Montemagno? Xam.Plugin.Connectivity? son casi parte de la libreria Xamarin.Essentials.